# Godot - Why does my Mesh deform at extreme locations?

Tags: mesh, game-development, godot

I am a beginner making a simple game and I modeled a robot and gave it controls. You basically walk around but there's gravity. It was working great until I let it fall for a long time, when I noticed something odd.

Here is how it looked before the problem:
[image: Before mesh deformation issue]

Then after I fell off the platform, at about -2000 on the y-axis, deformations became present:
[image: When mesh deformation issue became present]

It became particularly extreme at about -20,000 on the y-axis:
[image: When mesh deformation issue became extreme]

Is this simply a compression issue? I tried it both compressed and uncompressed and it happened both ways. Perhaps an issue in the Engine?

Comment: This might be a floating point accuracy issue. How large is your object? (What matters is the size of your object compared to 20,000, in the same units.)

Comment: @Arda That's a good point, my character is about 1x1x1 units large with many vertices in between. I initially thought that this might be due to a problem in the skeleton, but is this behavior to be expected just by the nature of floating points in extreme conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the numbers you've provided, it's clear you're experiencing floating point precision issues. The precise effect would depend on your platform, but the OpenGL ES Shading Language specifications have some minimum requirements for hardware manufacturers:

https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf (Section 4.5.2)

While The Khronos Group seem to have increased the minimum precision requirement for `highp` in a [newer edition of the specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf), which seems to be [the version required](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/GLSL-Versions) by OpenGL ES 3.0, I don't know what you're using exactly and how well your hardware conforms to it, so I'll go with the first specification I've linked. Based on that, GLSL floating point numbers have the following minimum precision:

```
highp  : 2^-16 = 0.0000153
mediump: 2^-10 = 0.000977
lowp   : 2^-8  = 0.00391
```

Assuming your hardware doesn't go beyond the minimum requirements, you'll have precision issues of about .3 units even with `highp` when you're 20,000 units from origin. Considering your vertices are within a 1x1x1 unit box, this equates to about a 30% error relative to the size of your object, which is in line with the images you've shared.

As a solution, try and keep your objects closer to the origin; shift your origin if/when needed.